# How do I ensure that Enthought Canopy's numpy and scipy are using the included intel mkl?

Tags: numpy, enthought

I don't think that numpy/core/_dotblas.so is using the included intel mkl on either my rhel or osx installation of Enthought's Canopy distribution.  Here is the output from ldd on both systems:

---

On RHEL (truncated output):

```
`$ldd _dotblas.so 
libmkl_gf_lp64.so => not found
libmkl_intel_thread.so => not found
libmkl_core.so => not found
libiomp5.so => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f50597a7000)
```

---

On osx I get (truncated output):

```
`$ldd _dotblas.so
_dotblas.so:
@rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libmkl_core.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libmkl_mc.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/libmkl_mc3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)`
```

---

None of the dylib files are in the @rpath location for osx (found via $otool -l  | grep LC_RPATH -A2)

How do I ensure that _dotblas.so (and lapack_lite.so) find the appropriate libmkl libraries?  The Canopy package manager does show MKL 10.3 as installed.  Where are those dynamic libraries actually installed (it seems like they're part of the 'core' virtual environment, but I still can't find them on either systems).

Thanks!

Comment: That's odd... What does `numpy.show_config()` output?

Comment: I think show_config() doesn't show actual library linkage on your system, but only the build script settings (not sure, but what I recall reading).  In any case, here is the osx output (similar for rhel) for for blas_opt_info:
    `libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'mkl_mc', 'mkl_mc3', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/vagrant/src/master-env/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/vagrant/src/master-env/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../include']`

Comment: Here's my band-aid fix for the rhel installation of Canopy - I extracted the libmkl*.so files from the installer and setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to them.  There's got to be a better way!

Comment: Glad that you got it working! I agree that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be a last resort.  It sounds like Enthought may using a non-standard path during building and not setting `LD_RUN_PATH` properly...  That's just a guess, but it would cause the issues you're seeing.  On the other hand, you'd think they would have caught something that simple, so it may be something more complex...